# Pandas read_gbq() does not load columns containing dots

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I am using read_gbq() to load a Big Query table into a Jupyter notebook with the following code:

```
# Define SQL query
sql = """
    SELECT *
    FROM `xxx.xxx.xxx`
    WHERE timestamp > TIMESTAMP('2021-03-11 00:00:00') AND timestamp < TIMESTAMP('2021-03-12 00:00:00')
    ORDER BY timestamp 
"""
# Run a Standard SQL query using the environment's default project
df = pd.read_gbq(sql, dialect='standard')
```

The table gets stored into df but columns with names containing a dot, e.g. `labels.type` do not get loaded (they are simply missing, no error is thrown). 
When I do the same query in BigQuery itself, I see the correct table in the Preview window (i.e. `labels.type` is not missing).

What might be the reason to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did not work because `labels.type` is a nested object/table. Strangely it is shown flattened in the Big Query preview. However, when running `` SELECT `labels.type` ... `` it also doesn't work in Big Query. 
To solve this, I selected `label` and used `pd.json_normalize()` to flatten it in my Jupyter Notebook.